# C# Type Mirroring

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

Is it possible in C# to have something I could call dynamic type mirroring, for lack of a better term?

Say, an application talks to a database that has multiple tables, each of which has an entity in the code of the usual sort:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
};
```

etc.

Now, is it possible to have a class that dynamically mirrors the types of these entities:

```
public class FilterType<T, U>
{
    T Field1;
    bool Apply<T>(T operand, T comparand);
};
```

such that `T` is dynamically `int`, for instance?

If I recall right, generics are compile-time determined, so this wouldn't be possible. Is there anything that could approximate this behaviour?

I need this to be able to filter fields in a table, and ideally I want this to be as generic as possible with minimal coupling. To add more substance, here's some code from my filter types:

```
public interface IFilter
{
    string Representation { get; }
}

public interface IFilterBinary : IFilter
{
    bool Apply<T>(T source, T operand1, T operand2) where T : IComparable;
}

public interface IFilterUnary : IFilter
{
    bool Apply<T>(T source, T operand) where T : IComparable;
}

public class IsGreaterOrEqual : IFilterUnary
{
    public string Representation { get; } = ">=";

    public bool Apply<T>(T source, T operand) where T : IComparable
    {
        return source.CompareTo(operand) >= 0;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that when I try to use the filters, I hit a snag:

```
var property = typeof (User).GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name == rule.FieldName);
var fieldValue = property.GetValue(user);
var fieldType = property.PropertyType;
var value = Convert.ChangeType(fieldValue, fieldType); // Here the return type is `object`, so this line is useless.
```

Applying the filter `filter.Apply(value, operand)` fails because `value` is an `object`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need this? How are you going to work with an object which has properties of types, which you don't know at design-time?

Comment: I would need it in more complex cases where the mirror isn't so simple, say if I want to perform some operations on the first field of the table without knowing its type beforehand.

Comment: i don't understand what you want to achieve @KristianD'Amato can you make an example?

Comment: I basically want dynamic filtering on several database tables, filters that would take into consideration whether the field is an `int` or a `string`, etc.

Comment: Have a look at `ExpandoObject`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: why not inherit from a base class with your two properties?

Comment: It is possible to do with code generation and reflection, but you very quickly fall off a cliff in terms of usability and place all reliance on runtime validation, no compile-time support. Looking at your pseudocode, C# offers nothing that can help at compile time. Seems like an XY Problem to me. Knowing what you want to achieve may help people provide a better solution that doesn't involve this approach.

Comment: I updated my question. I want to implement filtering behaviour on tables with several different types, hence the need to "mirror", so to speak.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato, can you provide how you filtering now and want filter with your mirror?

Comment: do you use EF? or something like?

Comment: @Grundy, yes, I'm using EF. I've provided some sample code above.

Comment: ypu can look to `DynamicLinq`

Comment: Looks like that might be it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94790/discussion-between-grundy-and-kristian-damato).

Comment: What type do you expect from Value? For example what do you want to write in next lines of code using value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better for you using [`DynamicLinq` lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/).

As for your current approach, if you use reflection for getting value, just use it for calling function, like this:

```
var property = typeof (User).GetProperty(rule.FieldName);
var fieldValue = property.GetValue(user);
var fieldType = property.PropertyType;
var result = filter.GetType().GetMethod("Apply").MakeGenericMethod(fieldType).Invoke(filter, fieldValue, operand);
```

but anyway in this case *result* was boxed to *object*.

Comment: I have changed the code like you suggested, with some modifications to make it work (like passing an array of `object`s rather than an object), and it does work. Having said that, I gotta admit it's ugly. So maybe going the DynamicLinq route might be better. I will accept this as the right answer in a while - let me give some time for others to answer too.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato, sure, that's why in first line i say about DynamicLInq :-)